# unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'str' Error for operations in a PandasDataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want this mini code to run but it shows:

```
 'unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'str''
```

How can I fix this ?

Here is a picture of the dataframe:

[image: Here is a picture of the dataframe]

```
import pandas as pd
btc = pd.read_csv('btc.csv',index_col='Date',parse_dates=True)
btc = btc['Price']
spy = pd.read_csv('spy.csv',index_col='Date',parse_dates=True)
spy = spy['Price']
stocks = pd.concat([btc,spy],axis=1).dropna()
stocks.columns = ['btc','spy']
stocks.pct_change(1).corr()
```

Comment: thanks for the help. but the code still dont run

Comment: Can you show the entire error message and the dtypes for the columns in 'stocks' df?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps your computer is set to read numbers with a ',' as the decimal separator instead of a '.'. Try:

```
import pandas as pd
btc = pd.read_csv('btc.csv',index_col='Date',parse_dates=True, decimal='.', thousands=',')
btc = btc['Price']
spy = pd.read_csv('spy.csv',index_col='Date',parse_dates=True, decimal='.', thousands=',')
spy = spy['Price']
stocks = pd.concat([btc,spy],axis=1).dropna()
stocks.columns = ['btc','spy']
stocks.pct_change(1).corr()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your column `spy` has the `object` data type, because it contains (not allowed) thousands separator `,`:

```
stocks.head()
```

> ```
>              btc        spy
> Date
> 2012-02-02   6.1   1,325.54
> 2012-02-03   6.0   1,344.90
> 2012-02-06   5.4   1,344.33
> 2012-02-07   5.7   1,347.05
> 2012-02-08   5.6   1,349.96
> ```

```
stocks.dtypes
```

> ```
> btc    float64
> spy     object
> dtype: object
> ```

Do this:

```
stocks["spy"] = stocks.spy.str.replace(",", "").astype(float)
```

just before your last command `stocks.pct_change(1).corr()`.